# Is there any way to ask Excel to multiply two columns (one by *10, the other by *100) and then take the average between them?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to work out how to ask Excel to calculate the average between two columns once they have been multiplied by 10 and 100 respectively. In my head I envisage the formula to look something like:

```
=AVERAGE(A1*10)(B1*100)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `AVERAGE` takes multiple arguments.

Comment: I can't test it, I don't use Excel, but the logical way would be `=AVERAGE( (A1*10), (B1*100) )` treating the entire function as that within the overall brackets, then each element (also bracketed so it will do the work first) separated by commas.

Comment: Thank you both! Adding the extra brackets solved it. Thanks very much. Is there anyway to accept an answer please?

Comment: You can answer it yourself using the hints provided [& also accept it as the preferred answer] , no worries. (We don't need the points;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=AVERAGE((A1*10),(B1*100))
```

[image]